# Facebook share counter reset after HTTPS

Tags: https, facebook, open-graph-protocol

I just moved my blog to https and, of course, all the facebook shares counters are now reset to 0.

I've spent several hours reading stuff online and I got the solution to point the og:url tag to the old urls (with http instead of https).

It worked for a day but now all the counters are back to 0.

The strange thing is that if I check the urls (both with https and http) with the open graph debugger it returns me 0 shares for both the urls!

I really don't know what to do! Is there a way to have back the counters of the http-version of the urls? Or, as an alternative, is there a way to sum the two counters?

p.s. I already activated the 301 redirect for the whole blog in my .htaccess file.

Comment: I ran into a problem when I changed domain name.  I couldn't keep my stats and comments, even with redirects:  [Preserve Facebook comments when the site changes domain name](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57734/preserve-facebook-comments-when-the-site-changes-domain-name)   I'm not sure if HTTP to HTTPS has the same issue.